# How to automatically set a CPU governor on boot?

Tags: root-access, kernel, scripts, cpu, processor

There are apps that can accomplish this task (e.g. "Kernel Adiutor" and others), however they in turn require other apps that can grant them root access to begin with, which is a lot of modification for this simple task.

In any regular Linux desktop system, setting the governor at every boot would be accomplished by creating a script, for example in `rc.local` or a systemd-oneshot, that simply calls `echo "<governor>" > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor` after each system start.

What would be the Android equivalent of this solution?

Is there any way to automatically set the CPU governor without installing any apps?

Comment: Rooting is mandatory to do this; apps like you mentioned make it easier though there may be command line solutions// Aside, Android only has a Linux kernel and not other features you find in Linux. [see this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/4339/131553)

Comment: As beeshyams said, unlike normal Linux distros, Android strictly restricts root access to the apps, and ultimately to the human user. See details here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213344/218526. So rooting your device is essentially required. Using third party app to set CPU governor is optional. You'll be able to do `echo` exactly the same way as you've been doing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run an executable on boot and keep it running?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213353/how-to-run-an-executable-on-boot-and-keep-it-running)